# Changing the status of an expense using state_machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a small expense tracking app using Rails 4.1. When a user submits the expense request, it's state is marked as pending by default. The admin has to approve the request. I'm using state_machine gem to do this.

Currently the Expense model looks like this

```
state_machine initial: :pending do
  state :pending
  state :approved

  event :approved do
    transition :pending => :approved
  end
end
```

When someone creates a new expense report, it's automatically marked as pending successfully. The workflow I'm thinking is that the admin will visit the expense/show page and use a drop down to approve the expense. However, I'm not quite sure to get this done the Rails way.

I tried using:

```
<%= form_for @expense do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :state_event %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :state_event, @expense.state_transitions, :event, :human_to_name, :include_blank => @expense.human_state_name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

in the expense/show page(I guess this is a dumb way to do this). The flash notice says that the expense is updated, but, the status change isn't reflecting in the DB. 
The update action looks like this:

```
def update
  @expense = Expense.find(params[:id])
  if @expense.save(expense_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Expense Report Updated"
    redirect_to @expense
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

private

def expense_params
  params.require(:expense).permit(:claim, :department_id, :expense_type_id, :expense_attachment, :state, :notes, items_attributes: [:id, :description, :amount, :issue_date, :_destroy])
end
```

Can someone suggest how to get this one done?

Comment: Please post the code for the update action too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `save(expense_params)` does not update the record with the params. Instead, use `update`:

```
@expense.update(expense_params)
```

Comment: If it's no bother, I have one more quick question. After updating the state, the drop down shows only the current state and not all others. For example, if I reject an expense, the approve and on hold don't show up in the menu any longer. How to make them show up?

Comment: `state_transitions` only includes the transitions defined for the current state.